# Instance constructor explaination

Tags: c#, oop

Could someone help me explain what is happening here. Not entirely sure what instance is all about.... Wouldn't I/ Couldn't I just use a static class.

I would appreciate if the following code would be annotated

```
public class Dingo
{
    public static Dingo instanceDingo;

    private Dingo(){}

    private static Dingo Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instanceDingo ?? (instanceDingo= new Dingo());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you see is a [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). And `??` is a null coalescing operator. You can research further on that topic.

Comment: @KarelG Thanks, I'll read up.